# Add a new Column in database which should have auto increment property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I need to add a column name Serial Number to my one of the database table,so that it should increment for each data,How to write this code in asp.net with c#

My connection string is as shown below

```
    cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=BOPSERVER;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True";
```

My database table is shown as below

```
   FID          varchar(10) Checked
   Placework    varchar(50) Checked
   DOJ          datetime    Checked
   Institute    varchar(50) Checked
   Year         numeric(18, 0)  Checked
  Duration          varchar(50) Checked
  Lastpost          varchar(50) Checked
  WorkingArea   varchar(50) Checked
  UpdateDate    datetime    Checked
```

In this table i need to add another column Sr.no that should automatically increment for every input and also FID and Sr.no should be composite primary key

Comment: First of all, why do you want to do it in code? Create a column with IDENTITY on the database table.

Comment: @ADNow After creating the column what to do next

Comment: Nothing much - it will automatically increment for every inserted row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, select the column that you want to increment. In the below pane in SQL Make Identity Specification to yes. Tour value of column will increase automatically.

Answer (score 1):

While this *can*  be done in C# code, since it's a one time operation it's better to be done directly on DB.

This can even be done visually in the designer, just add new column to the table and mark it as Identity.

Alternatively SQL code for this is:

```
   ALTER TABLE YourTableName
   ADD SerialNumber int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
```

This will create a column that will auto-increment its value starting with 1 with each record added.

Again, if needed this command can be issued from C# code via SqlCommand, but I would not recommend it.